# In Tkinter, are you able to insert a feature where the user can upload an image?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a project where students within my school can buy and sell their revision books with the purpose of it being cheaper and accessible. 
I will be using python 3.3 to program this system, with the aid of Tkinter. I am not fully used to the system, so this is where your help would be appreciated. One of the features on the system will allow the students to upload a picture of the book cover to show the condition and act as an image descriptor really. 
Will I be able to insert this feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Answering 'How' is out of scope for this site until you try something, fail, and post a specific question.  Include your OS in any further questions.

Two starting hints: The 3.x version of the pillow package, which you can install with 'pip', can be used to convert image files from one format to another.  Tcl/tk 8.5 can only handle .gif and .bmp files.  8.6 can also handle .png files.  On Windows, 3.4 comes with tcl/tk 8.6.  For this, among other reasons, I strongly recommend starting with the latest Python, currently 3.4.2, if you possible can.

That said, I suspect you would be better off writing a 'web' application, using a browser for the user interface to communicate with a server program that connects to a database.